# How to use Vue.use() in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the vuetify plugin in typescript.
In the documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start) it is indicated to use Vue.use (), but in typescript such error:

```
"error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'."
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
})
```

Comment: It would be better if you include some code to understand better your problem.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano, and when not. That option does not work in typescript.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano, how would this code look like typescript texts:

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
})

Comment: Thanks, I am not an expert in TypeScript, but now your question is understandable and somebody can answer it.

Comment: This is correct usage of Vue.use (TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript anyway). Problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking for the solution to this issue: When using VueJs + Typescript and you want use a plugin such as Vuetify or VeeValidate.

For example VeeValidate do the following:

`import Vue from "vue";`

`import VeeValidate from "vee-validate";`

`Vue.use(VeeValidate.install, { });`

Answer (score -2):

In tsconfig.json add to "compilerOptions" section:

`"module": "es2015"`